# Installing VMware ESXi 4.1 on Dell PowerEdge T610 using UEFI

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell-poweredge, uefi

I would like to know if it is possible to install VMware ESXi 4.1 on Dell PowerEdge T610 but using UEFI (not BIOS)...
I have seen some references on the net saying that **ESXi 4.1 is UEFI aware OS ?** while [**this post**](http://en.community.dell.com/dell-blogs/enterprise/b/tech-center/archive/2010/08/06/uefi-aware-os-deployment-on-dell-poweredge-servers-using-unified-server-configurator.aspx) does not list it as UEFI aware...

I actually tried it and although installation goes through, I cannot "Add Boot Option" in UEFI boot options. It sees Hypervisor as an option but there is no boot files listed to select from...

So I am wondering is this is possible at all...
Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to ask the same question on VMware communities and got the response that [ESXi v4.1 **does not** support UEFI](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/294787)